# Ionic - ngModel Not submitting the password field during the App Store review

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm developing an App and willing to submit it to the App Store, but i keep got rejected because the apple review team can't login with my demo account.

After checked with server logs, it seems that the password field was not submitted to my backend

```
problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits Bad Request: 
Validation failed for argument [0] in public 
org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<web.rest.UserJWTController$JWTToken> 
web.rest.UserJWTController.authorize(web.rest.vm.LoginVM): 
[Field error in object 'loginVM' on field 'password': rejected value []; 
codes [Size.loginVM.password,Size.password,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
codes [loginVM.password,password]; arguments []; 
default message [password],100,4]; default message [个数必须在4和100之间]]
```

But when I test locally, I can't reproduce this bug.

login.page.html

```
  <form class="login-form">
    <ion-input type="string" [(ngModel)]="account.username" name="username" placeholder="username"></ion-input>
    <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="account.password" name="password" placeholder="password"></ion-input>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 15px"></div>
    <ion-button expand="block" (click)="doLogin()" color="warning" fill="outline">login</ion-button>
  </form>
```

and my login.page.ts

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  account: { username: string; password: string; rememberMe: boolean } = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    rememberMe: true
  };

  constructor(
    public loginService: LoginService,
    public toastController: ToastController,
    public router: Router,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public doLogin() {
    this.loginService.login(this.account).then(
      () => {
        const toast = await this.toastController.create({
          message: 'log in success',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });
        await toast.present().then(() => history.back());
      },
      (err) => {
       \\ some error handle 
  }
}
```

I thought it might be the problem with the ngModel, but even after I change to dynamic forms, apple reports that the login button can't be click, my guess was that the data binding between html and model was broken, but I really just can't find why.

after change:

```
    <form class="login-form" role="form" (ngSubmit)="doLogin()" [formGroup]="loginForm">
      <ion-input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="邮箱"
                 formControlName="username"></ion-input>
      <ion-input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="密码"
                 formControlName="password"></ion-input>
      <ion-button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" type="submit" expand="block" color="warning" fill="outline">登录</ion-button>
    </form>
```

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  loginForm = this.fb.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
    rememberMe: [true]
  });

  constructor(
    public loginService: LoginService,
    public toastController: ToastController,
    public router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public doLogin() {
    this.loginService.login({
      username: this.loginForm.get('username')!.value,
      password: this.loginForm.get('password')!.value,
      rememberMe: this.loginForm.get('rememberMe')!.value
    }).then(
      async () => {
        const toast = await this.toastController.create({
          message: 'login success',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });
        await toast.present().then(() => history.back());
      },
      async (err) => {
        \\ some error handler
      }
    );
  }
}
```

ionic info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.26
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.26
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 21 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.14.0
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.10.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v14.1.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.1.0/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.5
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c
```

I really appreciate for any thought to solve this bug or let me reproduce the bug locally.

Best regards,

Wenjie

Comment: can't see any issue in the code. Did you get any issue with release build before submitting or did you find any issue with your testflight build? Should get issue on one of those. Also did they send any rejection screenshot? Could be issue with devices they were testing. They usually test it on ipad if ipad support is added on build

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I did test with a release build in Testflight in ipad,  I didn't find any problem like that, however in their screenshot did show that the password field is empty. I really don't understand why that could happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change every ion-input to native html input and solved the problem